# What is the character with the greatest number of strokes?

Tags: characters, orthography

I have seen an old and very rarely used character that consisted of four traditional dragons (龍). As I remember it meant "talkative."

That makes a total of 64 strokes, are there any other characters with more strokes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1. biang**

Well, the first one that came to my mind is **biang**, as in "biang biang mian" - which a quick [Wikipedia search shows has 58 strokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi%C3%A1ngbi%C3%A1ng_noodles). This is still in some use (and I've seen it in restaurants), if that means anything to you. It is not, however, found in dictionaries.

[image: biang]

**2. zhe**

Sadly however, biang doesn't have the most strokes (although I would argue it's the most complex) - [Wikipedia has a page on complex characters as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character#Rare_and_complex_characters), and according to them **zhe**, meaning verbosity, was the most complex/has the most stroke orders - possibly the character you are referring to, as it is just *long* (龍) times four:

[image: zhe]

**3. zheng**

It also mentions **zheng**, another 64-strokes character meaning flourish, as being equally as complex:

[image: zheng]

The page on [Wikipedia goes in to a lot more detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character#Rare_and_complex_characters), so I suggest you check it out.

Comment: You could say that 'zhe' is in fact "really, really, really long".

Comment: I'm sad to admit I lol'ed at that.

Comment: Intriguingly, there exists characters all the way through from one to four 'long'. I guess they ran out of characters, and had to start getting 'long'er and 'long'er.

Comment: Made me giggle at work, funny stuff

Comment: @Ciaocibai great answer! And many thanks for the link to the article

Comment: @LarsAndren Glad to be of service, and well worth it for the great comments from Williham!

Comment: when i started studying chinese years and years ago, biang looked really complicated... it looks simple now. makes me think of this book: http://www.quaritch.com/NewsItem.asp?id=117

Comment:  (tiè) duplicated vertically has 128 strokes, and is listed by Wenlin as the character with most strokes. There is no further information, though.

Comment: @Ciaocibai didn't see contact info in your profile. Hoping to ask for your thoughts on a startup idea making it easy to find & discuss interests (like discussing Chinese characters). Would you mind emailing info @ panabee.com?  Thanks!

Comment: In the unicode Unihan, there are only 2 characters with 64 strokes, the maximum amount it looks like,  and . There is no character with 128 strokes.