# What are Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese with the most strokes in the world?

Tags: characters

What are the simplified and traditional characters with the most strokes in the world? You can also tell me how many strokes that Chinese character has. I will be very grateful for any answers.

Comment: Please begin with [What is the most complex simplified character?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1645/8099) and [What is the character with the greatest number of strokes?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/668/8099).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters#Rare_and_complex_characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most complex character consisting of **58 strokes** is pronounced as [**biáng**].  Biang Biang Noodles – biáng biáng miàn is a typical noodles-dish that is famous and popular in China’s Shaanxi province.

[image] [biáng]

The most complicated, yet meaningful and can be found in a dictionary Chinese word is **龘 [dá,ㄉㄚˊ], 48 strokes**.

[龘（汉语拼音：dá/tà；注音符号：ㄊㄚˋ/ㄉㄚˊ; 粤拼：daap6）字是现时Big5码编码当中笔划最多的一个字，笔划达48划。这个字亦是中华民国一般字典中笔划最多的一个字。除此，该字也是全世界所有常用语言中，极为少见笔划相当多的单音节单字.]

[字义: 该字隶属龙部，古代同“龖”，是“龖”字之异体字。《说文》解作“飞龙”。《广韵》说该字之义为“龙飞之状”，龙在天空腾飞貌。]

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BE%98

[image]

They both counted as the most complicated character of the simplified and traditional Chinese.